# Disable UITableView floating section header tap-through?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a plain-style UITableView with custom section header views (pre-6.0, so not UITableViewHeaderFooterView). Some can be tapped, and others can't. When they're floating at the top of the table view above other cells, taps go through the header section to the table view cells below. Because of re-use requirements of this view elsewhere in the app, the section header view is a subclass of UITableViewCell. Is there a way to prevent the touch from going through?

If I change the subclass of the section header view to UIView instead of UITableViewCell the problem goes away. This solution isn't feasible for other reasons, however. Is there some special behavior in UITableViewCell that I can disable?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` instance method [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

You can override this method in your UIView subclass and return the view that you want to respond to the touch.

Using maybe this sort of approach:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    id hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (hitView == self) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return hitView;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. I've updated the original question to include that, because of re-use requirements of this view elsewhere in the app, the section header is a subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: UITableViewCell is a subclass of UIView so you should still be able to catch the touch.

Comment: Unfortunately overriding the hitTest:withEvent: method doesn't work. Returning both nil or self when the point is in the section view still results in the cell below appearing selected as well. The section receives the touch as well, though, since the attached action does trigger when tapping it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation.
I ended up placing a UIButton underneath the other stuff in my custom header cell and making it the size of the whole cell and making it blend in.

Now it catches the taps and does nothing, preventing tap through to cells underneath it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just make *user interaction enabled* `false` if you have access to section header view